# Add background image to uitableviewcell and change color when select row

Tags: uitableview, background-image, background-color

I set a background image to cell of uitableView using the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
 UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
   av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   av.opaque = NO;
   av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern_gray0.png"];
   cell.backgroundView = av;
```

I want when user presses the row change the color of row to green color and keep the background image at the same line.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `selectedBackgroundView` on your cell.

Comment: Where or how? could you show me sample code? I added this code `UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:170/255.0
                                                     green:211/255.0
                                                       blue:91/255.0
                                                        alpha:0.5];` to cellForRowAtIndexPath but not work.

Comment: Wherever you set backgroundView, you can set selectedBackgroundView. And make sure selection style is not "none". selectedBackgroundView is the view displayed for the cell in highlighted state.